# Passing data acquired from http request from one page to another

Tags: angular, http, firebase, angularfire2

I have this page where it displays a category list and if a user clicks on a certain category it will display the details of that category.

on my service:

```
getCategory(id) {
    const url = 'https://[project-name].firebaseio.com/category/' + id + '.json';
    console.log(url);
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => {
      const data = res.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
  }
```

on the Category list ts:

```
getCategory(id) {
    this.firebaseService.getCategory(id).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.logs(res);//returns back title, description, etc
      }
    );
  }
```

on the Category list HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/category-details' , tile.id]" mat-button color='primary' (click)="getCategory(tile.id)">View</a>
```

On my category-details I want the data from the category list to be passed to it and display the data. Below is the ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
   });
  }
```

I'm new with HTTP Request and I'm trying to learn more about this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the data in a shared service - one that is injected into both Components.

Answer (score 0):

On the Category List HTML

```
<a [routerLink]="['/category-details' , tile.id]" mat-button color='primary' (click)="getCategory(tile.id)">View</a>
```

you can write

```
<a [routerLink]="['/category-details' , tile.id]" mat-button color='primary'>View</a>
```

as both routerlink and (click) function is conflicting with each other. So its better that you only keep routerLink and get rid of (click) function.

After this in the category detail page you can fire HTTP request for getting data about the category by getting the id from params.